# How to have JAXRS endpoints in test folder

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to have a handfull of `REST` endpoints to check that my custom annotation is doing well in sending the desired error status.

As I dont want to deploy these at my customers, the natural choice should be to have my `@Path` endpoints in the **test/java** folder and have them discovered by the `JAXRS` implementation (in my case Jersey), through the use of `@ComponentScan` annotation.

Unfortunately, the magic does not happen.

What is the correct incantation ? Is there an ingredient missing in my recipe ?

My context is `Spring`, `Hibernate`, `Tomcat7`, `Jersey 2.2`

Comment: Do you want to test before deploying the application (using mock services) or after deploying it into a temp container (using HTTP Clients basically)?

Comment: This is to be part of the usual tests of the app. Run by Jenkins. There already is tests that launch their own tomcat along with the app. So they'll be run separately in the app , the test version (not deployed)

Comment: Do you want write and execute tests for your REST endpoints without running Tomcat separately?

Comment: @Justas Considering there is tests in my project that launch a temporary Tomcat, my thought was to put my endpoints in test/src. But, as written in the comments, those Tomcats run a war that discards the tests. So in the end, I tested my annotations differently. But anyway, having test-time endpoints is still something that could be useful

Answer (score 0):

If you want deploy a jersey project with tomcat with support of servlet 3 you have to provide resource config class for jersey

```
 public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
   public MyApplication() {
    packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
   }
}
```

for testing you can copy test classes using antrun plugin use this github url for reference gist.github.com/isopov/4387142

Comment: Thanks shivam, there is already such a class in the src/java folder.
My issue is that I want my endpoints to be in test/java so that they do not get deployed in the war built.

In fact this is my issue, my tomcats launched in the test phase are running the app that is built without the classes under test/java. THus the 404 error.

thanks for opening my eyes.

Comment: for testing you can copy test classes using antrun plugin  use this github url for reference https://gist.github.com/isopov/4387142

Comment: That's clever @shivam, trusty ant to the rescue. Will submit the idea to my coworkers.

I did a test class, annotated fields in it like I did with my jaxrs queryparams, then wrote methods where I call the validator on this. I catch the Validation exception and dig the cause to check the status is correct.